# How do you fix 'Parse' is not defined.?

Tags: parse-platform

I keep getting this error in my client/app.js file as I use grunt to compile it into production.  I never had this error before while in development.  I've not found any clear guidance on how to fix this on the client side.  I initialize Parse at the bottom of the page.

My app.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('cpApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ui.router',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'parse-angular',
  'angularPayments',
  'elif'
])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
  })

.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $cookieStore, $location) {
  return {
    // Add authorization token to headers
    request: function (config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token');
      }
      return config;
    },

    // Intercept 401s and redirect you to Landing Page
    responseError: function(response) {
      if(response.status === 401) {
        $location.path('/');
        // remove any stale tokens
        $cookieStore.remove('token');
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
      else {
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
    }
  };
})


    .run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
      Parse.initialize('key1', 'key2');
      // Redirect to card if route requires auth and you're not logged in
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
        Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
          if (next.authenticate && !loggedIn) {
            $location.path('/');
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Really? There is no one out there that can lend a hand to someone trying to deploy production to Heroku for the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in my config function. I needed to move Parse there from run:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, Parse) {
      Parse.initialize('Id1', 'Id2');
      $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
  })
```

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue.  May I ask how you inject Parse?

Comment: @Sam I use Angular fullstack so if you have a different framework you may need to make some adjustment.

1) In your app.js 
angular.module(app', [ 'parse-angular', 'parse-angular.enhance'])

2) In your index.html body. Make sure to put it after jquery.js and angular.js

<script src="../bower_components/parse-angular-patch/dist/parse-angular.js"></script>
      <script src="../bower_components/parse-js-sdk/lib/parse.js"></script>

I hope that helps.